# Error when I run npx create-react-app my-app

Tags: reactjs, npm, npx

I have tried these two commands and am getting the same error.

```
npm clean cache --force
npx create-react-app client -timeout=120000


$ npx create-react-app client -timeout=120000
npm WARN exec The following package was not found and will be installed: create-react-app
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.

Creating a new React app in C:\web_dev\MERN\projects\booking-app\client.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! errno ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash.sortby/-/lodash.sortby-4.7.0.tgz failed, reason: Socket timeout
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\web_dev\MERN\projects\booking-app\tmpnodejsnpm-cache\_logs\2021-12-29T13_37_03_989Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting client/ from C:\web_dev\MERN\projects\booking-app
Done.
```

Answer (score 1):

I have just faced the same issue when upgrading an old project. What solved, in my case was:

- If you use **yarn**:

```
yarn global remove create-react-app
yarn cache clean
```

- If you use **npm**:

```
npm remove create-react-app
npx clear-npx-cache
```

Also make sure there is no folder in the directory where you will created the new React project because you can get another warning similar to:

```
The directory . contains files that could conflict:

  <the file(s) name here>/

Either try using a new directory name, or remove the files listed above.
```

After that, `npx create-react-app .` ran smoothly.

Those steps described above solved the following subsequent warnings (versions may vary).:

1. Global warning

```
You are running "create-react-app" 4.0.3, which is behind the latest release (5.0.0).
We no longer support global installation of Create React App.
```

2. tar warning

```
tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
```

Answer (score 1):

Even I was getting the same error and then saw your question I closed all the task and run this command "npx create-react-app my-app" again it got solved!

Comment: This has already been mentioned in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem so I uninstalled it globally then reinstall:-

- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- npm uninstall create-react-app

Then I used npx:-

- npx create-react-app project-app

Tell me if this works for you

Comment: I have tried this. It didn't work. I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
npm install -g npm@latest
npm install node
npm install -g yarn
yarn cache clean
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error sometime ago,
just make sure you don't have any space between the name of your directories folders
like Desktop/react project/my-react-app ...this is wrong
try this
Desktop/reactproject/my-react-app ... correction

Answer (score 0):

You should try using a different network, either a different Wi-Fi network or using a mobile hotspot. Then, try again to create the react app: npx create-react-app <project_name>.

Hope this should help you.This Works For me.